# Prius 2011 Car sometimes does not turn on for 3 to 5 minutes

Tags: toyota, starting, prius

We have a 2011 Prius that sometimes does not start up right away. 
When we press the brake and power on the car, the lights will come up, but the READY symbol on the dash does not show up. We have to turn on and off the car maybe 4 or 5 times before the car actually starts up.

After this happens, the car usually runs fine for a whole week or month. Then right back to doing it again. This has been going on for about 6 months. And i'm ready to address it.

When the car doesn't start up, a whole bunch of car symbols show up, but I've never taken note of which are showing up, because it seems like the same symbols that show up right before the car boots up normally, but because the car doesn't fully start right away, those symbols stay on.

Any ideas what the issue is?

Update: Some have suggested I get the battery tested.

The battery reads **12.30 volts** when the car is completely off.

It dips down to **11.85 volts** when the car is first turned on.

And it jumps to **14.47 volts** when the engine kicks in.

These are the symbols when the car won't turn on.

[image]

Comment: also want to mention that I've noticed the time being off by 30 minutes once. (no) it wasn't after day lights savings. heh

Comment: One thing with electronic systems in general is that after a few years it can be worth disturbing every connector (when the equipment is switched off) because of a build-up of oxides at the metal/metal boundaries. This effectively "wipes" the contacts and provides a good connection.

Comment: The car is around 10 years, old i'm leaning toward it being the battery. I've never changed the 12V battery yet.

Comment: So, get the battery tested.

Comment: @weathervane I tested the battery myself and updated the question.